# IEnumerator While loop: Mathf.Lerp while game continues running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to lerp from a set of 2 values smoothly over 2 seconds, and then do the inverse over 2 seconds. I've been trying to use Mathf.Lerp or Smoothstep however it seems the value is changing just once and then not reaching the rest of the IEnumerator method. Is my problem with the IEnumerator implementation or within the Lerp?

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
            StartCoroutine(DistortScreenFX());
            puh.gm.score += 500;
            SoundManager.PlaySound("lightspeed1");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Asteroid")) {
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), GetComponent<Collider2D>());
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ability")) {
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), GetComponent<Collider2D>());
        }
    }


        IEnumerator DistortScreenFX() {

        ChromaticAberration abbFX; //ramp then reset to 0
        LensDistortion lensFX; //ramp then reset to 0

        pp.profile.TryGetSettings(out abbFX);
        pp.profile.TryGetSettings(out lensFX);

        var startTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        float duration = 2.0f;
        float t = 0;
        while (Time.realtimeSinceStartup < startTime + duration) {
            t = (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - startTime) / duration;
            abbFX.intensity.value = Mathf.SmoothStep(0.0f, 1.0f, t);
            lensFX.intensity.value = Mathf.SmoothStep(-25.0f, -100.0f, t);

            yield return null;
        }

        startTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        while (Time.realtimeSinceStartup < startTime + duration) {
            t = (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - startTime) / duration;
            abbFX.intensity.value = Mathf.SmoothStep(1.0f, 0.0f, t);
            lensFX.intensity.value = Mathf.SmoothStep(-100.0f, -25.0f, t);

            yield return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How are you calling this method? Is the MonoBehaviour running this coroutine active during the execution?

Comment: Are you sure your return type should be IEnumerator?

Comment: @mcrvaz I am using StartCoroutine(DistortScreenFX()) inside of a OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)

Comment: Are you destroying the game object on collision? Can you post the whole code?

Comment: @mcrvaz I've edited the main question to add the whole code concerning the problem.

Comment: The game object is indeed getting deleted, but i would assume as this is affecting the main camera that it wouldn't be the issue, i'll give it a shot moving the object destroy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are destroying the game object running the coroutine.
Place the `Destroy(gameObject);` at the end of the coroutine(after the last `yield return null`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this function using StartCoroutine(DistortScreenFX()) then most likely the function is throwing an exception which is causing it to terminate. Check the logs and see if there is an error.

If you are not using StartCoroutine to call it, then you are calling it wrong.

Comment: I see no errors in the logs, I am using StartCoroutine